# AngularJS URLs all of a sudden contain hashbang

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I've been developing an AngularJS app for the last month with `angular v1.5.8` and `angular-route v1.5.8` and `node v 7.1.0` (with `nvm`). All of a sudden, my urls contain a hashbang and the routing isn't working so I can't change pages.

Instead of

`http://localhost:8080/#/about` when I first load the page, I get `http://localhost:8080/#!/about`

and when I try to change to `http://localhost:8080/#/chat` by clicking a `<a href="#/chat">` I get `http://127.0.0.1:3000/#!/about#%2Fchat`.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I might have changed to result in this new behavior? I've removed my `node_modules` and `npm install`ed again and it still happens.

Relevant code is below

index.html

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/chat">Chat</a></li>
      </ul>
```

routes.js

```
angular.module('routes', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutController'
    })
    .when('/chat', {
      templateUrl: 'views/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/about'
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

look at  $locationProvider, its hashPrefix allows you to specify what you want to prefix your slash. if you want your code to work put the $locationProvider in your dependencies and enter the following

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')

config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('')
  $routeProvider
    .when('/about', {
      templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
      controller: 'AboutController'
    })
```